# How to vertlically align the content of a box to the center

Tags: html, css

In the following code I am trying to put all the headings be align vertically in the middle but it is not working with vertical alignment as you can see on my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/exp1zjh6/1/

html:

```
<div class="captions">
  <h2>design</h2>
  <h1>create</h1>
  <h2>print</h2>
</div>
```

css:

```
.captions { 
  display:flex;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
h1{
  font-size:28pt;
}
```

How can I put the h1 in the middle with the h2's?

Comment: With `flex` you have `align-items` property: `align-items:center;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.captions { 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
 justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: Well. it moves the h1 further up. But what I actually want is to move the h1 further up. like  - h1 -. Imagine that the dashes are h2. So you can see that h1 is in the middle with h2.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items: center;` to  **.captions**

```
.captions {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/exp1zjh6/3/)